# You cannot touch me, but I can touch you, who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.
>   I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.
>   I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

**Who am I?**

Comment: I like this puzzle so good job on its creation; however as you've probably noted from numerous answers which all fit as well as each other, it's probably a bit broad. I'm guessing there are even more answers that would fit as well. It can be difficult to try and come up with more answers to your puzzle once you know your intended solution, but I think on such short puzzles it's very common to be able to come up with things that could fit, so it might be better to try and make them longer. But take this all with a grain of salt as I'm not an avid puzzler!

Comment: I do understand the "problem" here, but I actually like the diversity of answers :)

Comment: I just saw an edit suggestion to this question. 'Twas not me though *raises hands*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could you be

> **music**?

You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.

> We can’t physically touch a piece of music as it’s being played, but music can touch us emotionally.

I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.

> Of course, music doesn’t have ears, but we do.

I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

> Musical pieces have very, very, very bad short term and long term memories, in contrast to our (somewhat) better neurological functions, which allow us to, among other things, follow a piece of music.

Comment: 'follow' could also be treated as "follow a playlist of music"

Comment: More specifically, rot13(ZP Unzzre) :p

Comment: That last spoiler block is hilarious.

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility:

> Wind

You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.

> You can feel the icy touch of the winter wind, but you cannot touch it.

I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.

> The wind has no ears, but you can often hear it.

I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

> "*Follow the wind, my boy!  See where it takes you!*"  I mean, it's metaphorical, but it works.

Comment: Good ideas! The "follow" part is the hardest in all answers, I think this works out quite okay :)

Comment: This was my first thought but I was not sure if I could make it work for all the hints. You did, congrats! And +1.

Answer (score 12):

Who am I?

> A Story

You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.

> Stories can certainly be touching. A book can be touched, but the story is not material so can't itself be touched.

I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.

> Stories can be told or read out loud. A story cannot hear the listener

I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

> I can follow a story, but it can't follow me.

Comment: This is awesome, I have to admit that you matched "follow" the best of all answers!

Comment: Another amazing answer!

Answer (score 10):

> Time

Touch

> 1. We cannot touch it, but it can touch us(certainly affect our actions).

Hear

> 2. Time cannot hear us, but we can certainly hear a clock (Clock represents Time in this context) ticking.

Follow

> 3. Time never follows us, but we should follow our Schedule (Schedule represents Time in this context).

Comment: creative thoughts!

Comment: Please tell me, how to hide the anwsers ?

Comment: @iCantC Preface them with `>!`

Answer (score 9):

You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.

> The Law. Figuratively, *the long arm of the law* can reach/touch anyone but the opposite is beyond even comprehension.

I cant hear you, but you can hear me.

> Perhaps, *hearing* here refers to *getting to know* the law.

I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

> Individuals can (actually must) follow the law. Again, the law can't (and doesn't need to) follow anyone.

Comment: One can argue that legislators can touch it. They can *retouch* it (amend) and they can do the *finishing touches* (review and edit drafts for voting) on it. I don't think your answer holds.

Comment: Agree! But _you_ (which actually translates to _me_ - an average jane/joe) can't touch it!

Comment: I have democratic powers. I can (by participating and pressuring my elected legislators, yadda yadda) touch it.

Comment: @Mindwin, I am sure you do and hope you use your powers to make the world a better place! :)

Answer (score 7):

Who am I?

> Advice

You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.

> You can't touch an advice, but good one can save you and bad one can hurt you.

I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.

> Advice doesn't hear, but you can hear it.

I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

> Advice won't follow you if you reject it, but you can follow an advice.

Answer (score 7):

What am I?

> A Dream

You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.

> A dream can touch you and make you feel emotions, but you can't actually touch inside a dream

I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.

> You can hear inside dreams, but a dream can't listen

I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

> A dream can't follow you, but you can follow your dreams.

Comment: +1 for the last part :P

Answer (score 4):

> You cannot touch me, but I can touch you.
>
> I can’t hear you, but you can hear me.
>
> I can't follow you, but you can follow me.

---

> *A narcissistic cult-leader who pretends to be a benevolent God.*
>  *No one is allowed to touch the Master.*
>  *The master does not listen, you listen or else.*
>  *The master does not prostrate. You prostrate.*
>  The riddle is you, not a malevolent God.